# Unable to perform HTML5 drag and drop using javascript for Selenium WebDriver test

Tags: javascript, jquery, xpath, selenium-webdriver

In order to implement drag and drop for Selenium tests, I referred to http://elementalselenium.com/tips/39-drag-and-drop There it's mentioned to use javascript(from https://gist.github.com/rcorreia/2362544) to handle drag and drop.

I implemented it as it is and it worked. But in my case, I've dynamic xpaths for source and target element. In order to achieve that, I tried with following code:

```
package org.test.selenium;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class HTML5DragAndDrop {
    WebDriver driver = null;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp(){
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        String chromeDriver = System.getProperty("user.dir")+ File.separator + "drivers" + File.separator + "chromedriver.exe";

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriver);

        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/drag_and_drop");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void tearDown(){
        driver.quit();
    }
  @Test
  public void testDragAndDrop() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      String filePath = "C://dnd.js";
      String source = "//div[@id='column-a']";
      String target = "//div[@id='column-b']";
      StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
      String line;
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
      while((line = br.readLine())!=null)
          buffer.append(line);

      String javaScript = buffer.toString();

      javaScript = javaScript + "$('" + source + "').simulateDragDrop({ dropTarget: '" + target + "'});";
      ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(javaScript);
  }
}
```

but it gives error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

(Session info: chrome=35.0.1916.153)

However, if use source and target as css like following, it works perfectly fine:

```
String source = "#column-a";
String target = "#column-b";
```

Can someone please suggest me changes that need to be done so that above will work with source and target elements with xpaths? In my case, I'm constrained to use xpath that's I've to do this with xpath only.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that JQuery uses CSS-like syntax. Xpath won't work in this case.

If you *must* use Xpath, you will have to convert the Xpath string to CSS before you append it into this JQuery string:

```
javaScript = javaScript + "$('" + source + "').simulateDragDrop({ dropTarget: '" + target + "'});";
```

If you are only using Xpath to identify `div`s using IDs, then you can try this in Java:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("'(.*?)'");
Matcher matcherSource = pattern.matcher(source);
Matcher matcherTarget = pattern.matcher(target);
String cssSource = "#" + matcherSource.group(1);
String cssTarget = "#" + matcherTarget.group(1);
javaScript = javaScript + "$('" + cssSource + "').simulateDragDrop({ dropTarget: '" + cssTarget + "'});";
```